# Question about how MIPS reads in decimals

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a very beginner grasp on MIPS as I am just starting to use it and the ins and outs of it so forgive me if this is a bad question.

I'm confused about how MIPS works with binary. I know that if I input a number say 500 it would get stored as 1F4 in the register but my question is I need to see the binary conversion of 500 (111110100) for part of my program, for example checking if the 7th digit of that number is a 1 or 0.

Without leading me directly to the answer could anyone guide me in the direction? I think I might be missing something.

Comment: Are you talking about the MARS / SPIM read-integer system call, or are you talking about `li $t0, 500`?  Neither of those are truly MIPS itself doing the conversion: the first is software (maybe running on a simulated MIPS), and the latter is done at assemble time.

Comment: Oh, nvm, you just want to check the 7th bit of a binary integer in a register, and it doesn't matter whether it was the result of a conversion from decimal, or whether it the result of an add or multiply or shift or whatever.  `andi $t1, $t0,  1<<7` / `beq $t1, $zero, target` to isolate that bit with a mask, and then branch on it being zero / non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to check the 7th bit of a binary integer in a register, and it doesn't matter whether it was the result of a conversion from decimal, or whether it the result of an add or multiply or shift or whatever.

Isolate that bit with an AND mask, and then branch on the resulting register being zero / non-zero.

```
  # Input in $t0
andi $t1, $t0,  1<<7
beq $t1, $zero, target
```

Or shift that bit to the bottom of a register and AND with `1` to get a 0 / 1 result in a register.

Comment: Sorry accidentally deleted the post. Your response was very helpful was got me past a question that was taking me forever to understand. But lets say I wanted to check a user inputted number, is there a way to check a certain digit with a value stored in the register?

Comment: @coding44: That's what this does.  It doesn't matter how you got a binary integer in a register, it's always just a 32-bit integer.  (Unless you got ASCII text input, and have a byte of a string or something.  But if you use the read-integer `syscall`, you will have a binary integer.  The MARS/SPIM syscall reads characters and does the conversion for you.)

Comment: Let's say 9 is the digit the user inputs along with some sort of decimal (the binary number I'll be checking) and the 9 gets stored in $t1, is there a way to call $t1 as the number that's being checked?

Comment: @coding44: yes, of course.  `ANDI` works with any combination of dest and source registers.

Comment: I'm getting an error when trying to do andi $t1, $t0, $t1 but I'm most likely doing it wrong. if I were to want to AND that last bit to isolate it to be checked is that the correct way?

Comment: @coding44: http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html shows that ANDI requires its 2nd source to be an immediate.  Are you wanting to use your runtime-input as the bit-position rather than number to be checked?  Use it as a shift count.

Comment: I'd like it so that I can use the inputted number as the position to be checked

Comment: @coding44: I already answered that in my last comment.  Use it as a shift count to bring that bit to the bottom of another register.

Comment: So then I would use sll correct? Andi doesn't let me use << in the last source.